# Typo in Silverman's Arithmetic of EC?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am reading Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves and on page 6 I see something that I cannot understand. It defines the set of $K$-rational points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as
$$\mathbb{P}^n(K)=\{[x_0,\dots,x_n]\in \mathbb{P}^n:\text{ all }x_i\in K\}.$$

The very next line is "Note that if $P=[x_0,\dots,x_n]\in\mathbb{P}^n(K)$, it does not follow that each $x_i\in K$. However choosing some $i$ with $x_i\neq 0$ it does follow that $x_j/x_i\in K$."

It says "$\text{all }x_i\in K$" then "it does not follow that each $x_i\in K$". Does this seem odd to anyone else?

Comment: Perhaps it could be referring to the different representations a point can have, like $[\pi,\pi]=[1,1]$ so $[\pi,\pi]\in\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: Yes. The set of K-rational points of projective is the set of points, which have *some* homogenous presentation $[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ st $x_i\in K$. The comment says that even if there is some such presentation for a point, there might be another for the same point, where this is not the case (eg $[\lambda x_0,\dots,\lambda x_n]$, where $\lambda\in \bar K^*\backslash K^*$).